# How to edit hosts file using a batch file (check for line, add if not existing and delete if existing)?

Tags: batch-file, hosts

I have a batch script to add several lines to my hosts file to block certain websites on my computer.

I would like to use the batch script in such a way that when I run my `example.bat`, it first checks if the lines to add exist, and if they don't then add them. But the batch file should delete the lines in case of existing already in `hosts` file. In other words the batch file should toggle the presence of the lines in the `hosts` file.

How could this be done?

Here is what I have so far. All it does is adding the lines.

```
@echo off

:: BatchGotAdmin
::-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SystemRoot%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SystemRoot%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have administrator privileges.
if not errorlevel 1 goto gotAdmin

echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) >"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
set params=%*
if defined params set params=%params:"=""%
echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B

:gotAdmin
pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"
::--------------------------------------

@echo off

set hostspath=%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

echo 127.0.0.1 www.example1.com >> %hostspath%
echo 127.0.0.1 www.example2.com >> %hostspath%
echo 127.0.0.1 www.example3.com >> %hostspath%

exit
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A pure batch code with explanatory comments:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "hostspath=%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"

rem Initialize the array of our hosts to toggle
for %%a in (
    "127.0.0.1 www.example1.com"
    "127.0.0.1 www.example2.com"
    "127.0.0.1 www.example3.com"
) do (
    set /a numhosts+=1
    set "host!numhosts!=%%~a"
)

>"%hostspath%.new" (
    rem Parse the hosts file, skipping the already present hosts from our list.
    rem Blank lines are preserved using findstr trick.
    for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%a in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /n /r /c:".*" "%hostspath%"') do (
        set skipline=
        for /L %%h in (1,1,!numhosts!) do (
            if "%%b"=="!host%%h!" (
                set skipline=true
                set found%%h=true
                echo - %%b 1>&2
            )
        )
        if not "!skipline!"=="true" echo.%%b
    )
    for /L %%h in (1,1,!numhosts!) do (
        if not "!found%%h!"=="true" echo + !host%%h! 1>&2 & echo !host%%h!
    )
)
move /y "%hostspath%" "%hostspath%.bak" >nul || echo Can't backup %hostspath%
move /y "%hostspath%.new" "%hostspath%" >nul || echo Can't update %hostspath%
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: To be shure the casing dosn't matter I'd change `if "%%b"=="!host%%h!"` to `if /i "%%b"=="!host%%h!"` and reset numhosts at start.